# 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND' on Vercel Serverless API typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, serverless, vite, vercel

I've created a Vite project (Vue3 and Typescript) and thank to Vercel I've also created different endpoints that allow retrieving some data.

My idea is to have a `\api` folder with all the endpoints, and another `\backend` with all the business logic, so the file system would be like this:

```
api\
    index.ts
backend\
    enum.ts
    consts.ts
    logic.ts
src\
    ... vue files ...

.eslintrc.json
.prettierrc
tsconfig.json
...
```

But, recently I've deployed a new version of the app and the serverless api (`api\index.ts`) stop working because it cannot find the module `../backend/const.ts`.

The stack trace is the following:

```
2023-01-07T09:43:18.189Z    XXX ERROR   Error: Cannot find module '/var/task/backend/const' imported from /var/task/api/index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:328:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:965:10)
    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:909:12)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1173:79)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:841:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

In the `index.ts` to import all the needed constants and functions I'm using the notation `import { a } from '../backend/const'`, but it appears that is not valid anymore.

- I've already tried to move all the files inside the `api` folder (in a single file to not exceed the maximum api endpoint allowed) but it didn't work.
- I've tried to update the references, but it didn't work.
- I've tried to re-deploy everything, but it didn't work.
- I've tried to change the node version (from `16` -> `18`), but it didn't work.
- I've tried to change the `target` in `tsconfig.json` from `ESNext` to `ES2019`, but it didn't work.

The weird thing is that it works in the local environment but not in prod.

Does somebody have some ideas to fix or debug this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://github.com/vercel/community/discussions/1225

For now, you can set `VERCEL_CLI_VERSION` as environment variable in your Vercel Project to `vercel@28.10.2`.

Comment: thanks. you save my day. question? since what version that doesn't works anymore?